# installing doesn't resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_finance'

Tags: python, matplotlib

The title says it all. Upon trying to run code related to this  [matplotlib candlestikck tutorial](https://saralgyaan.com/posts/python-candlestick-chart-matplotlib-tutorial-chapter-11/), I got the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5aa61276079d> in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import yfinance
----> 4 from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
      5 import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates
      6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_finance'
```

So I installed it and restarted the kernel but still no dice. Next, I followed someone's advice on here and installed mplfinance and restarted the kernel, again no go. I rebooted, nil. I even tried installing "mlp_finance" as another answer on here suggested hoping it was some weird name clashing thing but again it didn't work. Why cannot I import mplfinance?

Addition 202007311328: this is a jupyter notebook; I can install and import fine on the command line. Installing mpl_finance from inside jupyter with "!pip3 install mpl_finance" produces no error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: mpl_finance in /home/pi/src/pyfin1/pyfin1.env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /home/pi/src/pyfin1/pyfin1.env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mpl_finance) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in /home/pi/src/pyfin1/pyfin1.env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->mpl_finance) (1.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /home/pi/src/pyfin1/pyfin1.env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->mpl_finance) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /home/pi/src/pyfin1/pyfin1.env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->mpl_finance) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/pi/src/pyfin1/pyfin1.env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->mpl_finance) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /home/pi/src/pyfin1/pyfin1.env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->mpl_finance) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/pi/src/pyfin1/pyfin1.env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->mpl_finance) (1.14.0)
```

but the same error happens when I try to import it.

edit 2020071343 here's an image of my tying to install mplfinance and then use it. anything pop out at you?
[image: jupyter notebook sequence of installing and importing mplfinance]

solved, see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3311

Comment: Are you sure thta: pip install mpl_finance ended without errors ?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python on your machine?

Comment: my understanding is that `mpl_finance` is [deprecated](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl-finance), but that [`mplfinance`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) has taken its place. Perhaps you could try that instead?

Comment: I'm trying to do it inside a jupyter notebook and maybe that has something to do with it? I can install and import it ok in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, unless the module has been misspelled (which doesn't appear to be the case based on your screenshot above), `ModuleNotFoundError` usually indicates that the **install location** is not within the **search path** for importing modules.

Since this is working for you under ipython, so have a simple way to find where your system installed mplfinance:

```
In [1]: import mplfinance as mpf
In [2]: mpf.__file__
```

To find out where your system is searching for modules

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If you run the above for both `ipython` and in your `jupyter notebook`, I am guessing that you will find that **`sys.path`** is *different* for your ipython installation than it is for your jupyter notebook (and that the notebook's search path does not include the install location).  This could be for various reasons such as environment variables, where jupyter is installed, whether you are running virtual and/or conda environments, etc.  You can read more about the module search path here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Note that if you are using a virtual environment, or conda environment, you have to (1) activate the environment *before* installing `mplfinance` and (2) activate the environment before running jupyter notebook.  It may also be necessary to have a separate install of jupyter notebook **in the activated environment.**

Let me know if the above gives you enough information to resolve the issue.  If not, please provide the output from the above commands and I will do what I can to help further.  All the best.  --Daniel

Comment: deleting  ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json resolves the issue

Comment: For the record (from @spring_chicken) : https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3311

Answer (score 0):

This had happened to me once. In my case the problem was:

Usually pc had 2 versions of python installed - Python 2, Python3. If you run pip install.. . It just install that module to python2 or Python3 by own.

Solution :
If your program runs under python3

```
python3 -m pip install mpl_finance
```

If your program runs under python2

```
python2 -m pip install mpl_finance
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: hi. This is all in a virtualenv container thing (you start it with source ./bin/activate). I'm trying to run it in a jupyter notebook which may be part of the problem? I can install and import it from the console but not inside jupyter.