# Can't import mpfinance to Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook

I've tried importing mplfinance to Jupiter but got stuck with the following error

Code:

```
import mplfinance
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
```

And both previous lines gave this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mplfinance'

Most of the similar problems I found were about mpl_finance since it was deprecated, but I can't understand why the new package name gives the same error.

I could easily import this package in PyCharm for example, so I have no idea why I can't do the same in Jupiter.

UPD: found a similar bug report on GitHub but with no answer [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/230)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to run `ipython` and import from the ipython prompt?

Or simply run `python` and import at the python prompt?

Please see also this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211986/1639359

If you ***can*** import mplfinance from either `python` or `ipython` then the above stackoverflow link will tell you how to find out where it is installed.  If not, then another way to find out where it is installed is to run `pip uninstall mplfinance` ... then `pip uninstall` will print out the location of the installed package and ask you "Proceed (y/n)?" ... at which point you can say **no** and don't uninstall it, but now you know where it is installed.

Let me know if any of the above helps or not.

P.S. Actually just read more carefully that you *can* import with PyCharm, so this sounds very similar to the GitHub post that you quoted which actually does have an answer now.  Good luck.